# Filling in null values in one column based on aggregate of a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning some basic data science, and I am working on the titanic dataset. The 'Age' column has null values which I'd like to fill with the average of a different column, say 'Pclass' or 'Sex'.

'Pclass' refers to Passenger Class and has three values (1,2,3) based on the whether the passenger had a 1st, 2nd or 3rd class ticket.

I am trying to generalize this process by writing a function that takes in two column names, 'Age' and the column we want to use to aggregate. I can't think of how I can completely generalize this, so for now, let's say I aggregate based on Pclass.

I got the mean age based on Pclass as follows:

```
# Figure out the mean age for each class
mean_age = round(df_train.groupby('Pclass').mean()['Age'])
mean_age
```

I tried to define the function as follows (38,30 and 25) are from mean_age:

```
def fill_age(data, col1, col2):
    if data[col1].isnull():
        if data[col2] == 1:
            return 38
        elif data[col2] == 2:
            return 30
        else:
            return 25
    else:
        return data[col1]
```

And tried to use .apply():

```
df_train['Age'] = df_train.apply(fill_age(df_train,'Age','Pclass'), axis = 1)
```

What am I getting wrong here, and how do I think about this to fix it and further generalize it?

Edit: The following line seems to have worked, but I need it to apply the changes to the dataframe itself, and I can't use 'inplace' with .apply()

```
df_train.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(round(x.mean())))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call the function inside `apply`, instead pass the function and the arguments via `args=()` or keyword arguments:

```
df['Age'] = df.apply(fill_age, col1='Age', col2='Pclass', axis=1)
```

But there's a better way to do this, via vectorization:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite far enough to understand vectorization, but I will keep this in mind!
I also managed to do it as 
```
df_train['Age'] = df_train.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(round(x.mean())))
````
Is there anything wrong about doing it this way?

Comment: @MushyMush Nothing wrong with a groupby solution; I've edited my answer with a faster and cleaner version of your code. Avoid using apply though, it is slow.

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much!